# Жить за/на мой счёт

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как грамотнее: жить на или за чужой счёт?

[18:52](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC+%22%D0%A1%D1%8B%D0%BD%22+1955&tbm=vid)

Answer (score 1):

В словаре синонимов:
[жить **за** чужой счёт](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-synonyms-term-20185.htm) — *жить **на** чужой счёт*, дармоедничать, есть чужой хлеб, быть на шее, сидеть на шее, жить за чужой спиной, тунеядствовать.

Оба фразы правильны и по смыслу равнозначны. Стоит, правда, отметить, что с предлогом **за** устойчивое выражение привычнее и употребляется гораздо чаще.

*Мужчина-то свою проблему решил, часть долга вернул, тем самым как бы заявив, что он не захребетник и **за чужой счёт жить** не намеревается* (А. Маринина. Бой тигров в долине).

*Зачем он предложил ей деньги? Чтобы потом упрекнуть в том, что она **живёт на чужой счёт**?* (Т. Устинова. Мой личный враг)

*Борис, которому нечем жить, протискивается по милости своей пресмыкающейся матери в гвардию и **живёт там на чужой счёт**, чтобы только быть на виду...* (П. Бирюков. Биография Льва Толстого)